# How do I ensure a process is running, even if it kills itself? (it needs to be restarted then)

Tags: linux, boot, process, cron, ruby

I'm using linux. I want a process (an irc bot) to run every time I start the computer. But I've got a problem: The network is bad and it disconnects often, so I need to manually restart the bot a few times a day. How do I automate that?

Additional information:
The bot creates a pid file, called bot.pid
The bot reconnects itself, but only a few times. The network is too bad, so the bot kills itself sometimes because it gets no response.

What I do currently (aka my approach ;) )
I have a cron job executing `startbot.rb` every 5 minutes. (The script itself is in the same directory as the bot)

The script:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
require 'fileutils'

if File.exists?(File.expand_path('tmp/bot.pid'))
  @pid = File.read(File.expand_path('tmp/bot.pid')).chomp!.to_i
  begin
    raise "ouch" if Process.kill(0, @pid) != 1
  rescue
    puts "Removing abandoned pid file"
    FileUtils.rm(File.expand_path('tmp/bot.pid'))
    puts "Starting the bot!"
    Kernel.exec(File.expand_path('./bot.rb'))
  else
    puts "Bot up and running!"
  end
else
  puts "Starting the bot!"
  Kernel.exec(File.expand_path('./bot.rb'))
end
```

What this does:
It checks if the pid file exists, if that's true it checks if `kill -s 0 BOT_PID == 1` (if the bot's running) and starts the bot if one of the two checks fail/are not true.

My approach seems to be quite dirty so how do I do it better?

Comment: Monit can be a very handy utility for things like this. Configuration is not onerous, either. Here: http://mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html and here: http://mmonit.com/wiki/Monit/ConfigurationExamples

Comment: Also, take a look at swatch and dwatch. They are watch daemons that can do a variety of things when a process is halted. They can even reboot the machine in some circumstances.

Comment: It seems that you may want to use the [Process](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Process.html#method-c-abort) class to help you manage your child processes.

Comment: ok thx, I did something similar: I wrote a quick loop script which runs my script as soon as it quits, what it does as soon as the bot kills itself ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cross-posted my question to stackoverflow.com, where I got the answer ;)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13627784/1081936

> Restarting a application is a bad workaround, not a solution.
>
> i recommend to review the documentation of your bot, look for a option
>   to configure after how many bad retries it exits or how to disable
>   this functionality completely. if the bot is open source, you can also
>   review its source code and modify the retry code. Try to find a clean
>   solution.
>
> if you really want to restart it, i would create a shellscript that
>   runs the bot in a loop. make sure bot.rb does not fork into the
>   background:
>
> ```
> #/bin/bash
> for (( ; ; ))
> do
>      ./bot.rb
> done
> ```
>
> you can run that script with  `nohup ./startscript.sh &` so it does
>   not terminate if you close the console.

Comment: thanks for the reminder, I wasn't able to accept it immediately because I hadn't got enough reputation :P